# JSON - Validate Form Data

Tags: json, forms, validation

I used xml earlier and learning JSON now. To restrict the user to enter garbage values for form fields such as address etc, in XML we can define a complex object in schema file. But using JSON How can do that? JSON accepts any data from the user. Could any one please provide me ideas or an example code?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do validation with schemas in JSON :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_Schema

depending on what you need to validate :

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html

Online tool for testing :

http://www.jsonschema.net/

Comment: Thank you very much for the links ibiza.

Comment: @user686608 You should mark the answers provided by other users to your questions as Accepted if you consider they helped you sufficently.